# Find MAX(Avg(value)) after grouped by two fields

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

The table name is `c_list`.

```
Country   City      Rating   Date
------------------------------------
France    Brest     95       24092016       
France    Brest     98       27092016
France    Brest     95       03102016
France    Lille     100      26092016     
France    Lille     92       28092016
Japan     Tokyo     98       02102016
```

There are more than 50 different countries and each country have few cities. And each city may have more than one row of record or more. I want to select one **City** with highest average **Rating** (Compare to Cities in it's own country) and then compare with all other cities in different countries. So, the final query should display all **Country** and their **ONE City** with max(avg(**Rating**)) and in desc order. The sample output:

```
Country   City        max(avg(rating))   
-------------------------------------
 USA      New York    97.25
 UK       Cardiff     96.70
 Germany  Greven      96.50
 Turkey   Afyon       94.88
 France   Guipavas    94.10
 Canada   Cartwright  91.35
```

I can only get the max(avg(rating)) for one country. Need help.

```
SELECT top 1 country, city, Avg(rating) AS Ratings
FROM c_list
where country = 'France'
GROUP BY city, country
order by Ratings desc
```

(Edited) The result that I want is similar like Miss world contest. Compete and win against local contestant in your country first. Next (my final result set) is to compete against the winners from other countries and rank them first to last using their avg(rating) that they got eatlier in their country.

Comment: This is for `Ms-access` or `Mysql`

Comment: I'm not familiar with ms-access syntax so I won't try to write SQL, but try splitting your queries in two.. One finds which city has the highest average rating while the other joins that list of cities with the countries. Try this approach

Comment: i am using ms-access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If am not wrong you are looking for this

```
SELECT country, 
       city, 
       Avg(rating) AS Ratings 
FROM   c_list A 
GROUP  BY city, 
          country 
HAVING Avg(rating) = (SELECT TOP 1 Avg(rating) AS Ratings 
                      FROM   c_list B 
                      WHERE  a.country = b.country 
                      GROUP  BY city 
                      ORDER  BY ratings DESC) 
ORDER  BY ratings DESC
```

**Note :** If you are using `Mysql` the replace `TOP` keyword with `LIMIT`

Comment: its not only france. i want answer for all countries n their city with highest rating.

Comment: @Yithirash - Remove the France from `Where` clause. Updated the answer check now'

Answer (score 0):

> Base table:

select t.* from temp_lax t
    COUNTRY CITY    RATING
1   France  Brest   95
2   France  Brest   98
3   France  Brest   95
4   France  Lille   100
5   France  Lille   92
6   Japan   Tokyo   98

Query:

select t1.country, t1.city, Avg(t1.Rating) rating
  from temp_lax t1
 group by t1.country, t1.city
having avg(t1.rating) = (select max(avg(rating))
                           from temp_lax t2
                          WHERE t1.country = t2.country
                          GROUP BY t2.city)
 order by rating desc

OUTPUT:
    COUNTRY CITY    RATING
1   Japan   Tokyo   98
2   France  Lille   96
3   France  Brest   96

Please let me know if you are looking for different result set.

> 

Comment: not exactly correct. your resultset has two cities from same country (france). but what im looking for is one city per country.